# Multiple countdown timer in onepage using javascript with setintervals

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am displaying countdown timer for one post at a time.
How to display multiple countdown timers to all posts which are coming from while loop.
each post having one date so

```js
var end = new Date('10/19/2014 10:1 AM');

    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
    var timer;

    function showRemaining() {
        var now = new Date();
        var distance = end - now;
        if (distance < 0) {

            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

            return;
        }
        var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

       // document.getElementById('days').innerHTML = days + 'days ';
       // document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML += hours + 'hrs ';
       // document.getElementById('min').innerHTML += minutes + 'mins ';
        //document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += seconds + 'secs';
   document.getElementById('days').innerHTML = days ;
        document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML = hours;
        document.getElementById('min').innerHTML = minutes;
    }

    timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="days"></span><span class="body_txt6">Days</span> <span id="hours"></span><span class="body_txt6">h</span> : <span id="min"></span><span class="body_txt6">m</span></p>
```

by using that date display countdown time.

Comment: I think you need an identifier for each timer right now you don't have any identifier for countdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ghomelistingse1").each(function() {
        var str_enddate = $(this).html();
    
var end = new Date(str_enddate);

    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
  var now = new Date();
        var distance = end - now;
  
  
 var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);
    if (distance < 0) {
  $(this).html("Expired");
 
  }
  else{
        countdown($(this), days, hours, minutes, seconds);
  }
    });
    
    function countdown(element, days, hours, minutes, seconds) {
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            if(seconds == 0) {
                if(minutes == 0) {
                    if(hours == 0) {
                        if(days == 0) {
                            return;
                        }
                        else {
                            days--;
                            hours = 23;
                            minutes = 59;
                            hours = 60;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        hours--;
                        minutes = 59;
                        seconds = 60;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    minutes--;
                    seconds = 60;
                }
            }
            seconds--;
            element.html(days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s");
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Month/ Date / Year
Example:  10/25/2014
<br/>
Date: 09/29/2014   <br/>
<span class="ghomelistingse1">09/29/2014</span>
<hr>

Date: 11/19/2014   <br/>
<span class="ghomelistingse1">11/19/2014</span>
<hr>
Date: 10/24/2014   <br/>
<span class="ghomelistingse1">10/24/2014</span>
```